# iOS MPVolumeView Not Responding to Hardware Volume Changes After Audio Streaming Starts

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, avaudiosession, mpvolumeview

I've integrated `MPVolumeView` into my view, and it correctly responds to hardware volume changes as expected. However, once I initiate audio streaming using `AVAudioEngine` to capture microphone audio and `AudioUnit` for decoding, the MPVolumeView ceases to reflect changes made using the hardware volume buttons. Additionally, even when I adjust the volume using the slider on MPVolumeView, it doesn't change the system volume. Has anyone else encountered this issue? What might be causing MPVolumeView to stop responding to hardware volume changes once streaming starts?

For the `AVAudioSession.Mode`, I use the `default` setting because using `.voiceChat` prevents `MPVolumeView` update from device volume changes permanently.

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.allowBluetooth])
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` for `AudioComponentDescription` was the issue.